# Cannot read property 'has error' of undefined ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to apply validation to the form in Ionic v3 and this error is popping up. Is there any other method for validation in ionic? 
The code is as below:

```js
//Type Script Code

export class HomePage {

formgroup:FormGroup;
firstname:AbstractControl;
lastname:AbstractControl;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public formbuilder:FormBuilder) {

  
this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({
  firstname:['',Validators.required],
  lastname:['',Validators.required]
});
  
this.firstname = this.formgroup.controls['firstname'];
this.lastname = this.formgroup.controls['lasttname'];
}
```

```html
HTML Code

<form [formGroup] class="validation-errors">
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>
First Name    
  </ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" formcontrolName="firstname">
</ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item *ngIf="firstname.hasError('required') && firstname.touched">
    <p style="color:red"> First name is required</p>
  
  </ion-item>

<ion-item>
```

Comment: did you try to check if firstname has a value first? "*ngIf="firstname && firstname.hasError('required') && firstname.touched". Another approach is to try to assign the firstname in ionViewDidLoad(){}

Comment: I noticed you're not binding your `formgroup` property to the `formGroup` input. ```<form [formGroup]="formgroup" class="validation-errors">``` I think it should be like that.